# My toyota vios 2008 green temp light keeps blinking when switch on and car won't start. How to fix this?

Tags: cooling-system

My toyota vios green temp.light came on and the car won't start. The cooling fan keeps on running . But everything seems to be ok. I replaces the etc sensor but stil it won't start. Any idee what the problem can be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: "Car won't start" is vague and unhelpful. What happens when you turn the key to "Start:" Do you hear clicking? Does the starter motor operate? Do you hear a screeching or clanging? Does the starter motor turn the car engine over, but the car engine does not begin running?